# Ordering of user list to take badges into account

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The user list is ordered by reputation points but it doesn't take into account the number of badges a user has.

For example, the following users all have 646 points, but the user with the least badges is actually placed above these other two who have more badges.

[image: user list]

https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=3000&tab=reputation&filter=all

Wouldn't a more complete solution would take into account the badges to order the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ranking (ordering) among the users having same reputation is based on the concept that who is the first one to reach that reputation. AFAIK, that's the status by design and IMHO, fair decision.

P.S - FWIW, The full snapshot is in contrast with your version `"the user with the least badges is actually placed above these other two who have more badges"`. It is not in ascending order by number of badges.

[image]

Comment: I didn't realise it was in order of who got there first. That does make sense and seem fair. Thanks

Comment: Ps. Sorry, I didn't mean to insinuate that it was in ascending order - I was just trying to illustrate the point that the badges weren't taken into consideration.